# How do I pass an input via binding to a custom property in UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF. I have defined a custom UserControl called `MyCustomControl`. It has a `DependencyProperty`: `MyProp`. I'm trying to pass a value from MainWindow using Binding. But somehow `MyProp` isn't getting that value.

**MyCustomControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    public int MyProp
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropProperty, value); }
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyProp), typeof(int), typeof(MyCustomControl));

    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        // DataContext = this; I tried including this line too :(
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void someFunction()
    {
        // MyProp is 0 here.
    }
}
```

**MyCustomControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyProject.MyCustomControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="MyProp:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProp}" />     <!-- MyProp is O here too -->
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public int TestProp { get; set; } = 5;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="400"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical">
        <local:MyCustomControl MyProp="{Binding TestProp}" />   <!-- Not working?? -->
        <local:MyCustomControl MyProp="24" />   <!-- This works!!? --> 
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
<local:MyCustomControl MyProp="24" />
```

This line works and it displays 24. But when I pass `{Binding TestProp}` its not working. It's not taking the value defined in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.

Could someone please help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're overwriting the user control's correct data context, inherited within the window, with a reference to itself, which breaks the binding to `TestProp`. See duplicate. A third option other than the ones offered there would be to set the `StackPanel.DataContext` in the `UserControl` to `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`. Lots of ways to do it really; the main thing is to _not_ change the `UserControl.DataContext`, because that's critical to make any bindings _targeting_ the user control work properly.

Comment: I will also point out that WPF was telling you what the problem was, if you'd just look. In the debugger console, you'll find an error like this: _"System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TestProp' property not found on 'object' ''MyCustomControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=TestProp; DataItem='MyCustomControl' (Name=''); target element is 'MyCustomControl' (Name=''); target property is 'MyProp' (type 'Int32')"_. ...

Comment: ... I.e. it's saying exactly that it can't find the `TestProp` property, _and_ it's telling you what object it's looking for the property on, which isn't your `MainWindow` class like you'd expect. Any time a binding doesn't work as you expect it to, the first place you should look is in the debugger console. The vast majority of the time, there will be an error message there telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time pointing out the issue and the solution. Much appreciated.